# Meteor mobile app and dashboard

Tags: mobile, meteor, dashboard

- website
- mobile app
- dashboard

I want to use these 3 app in single meteor project . Is this possible ? if so how can i do this ?

Comment: This question is extremely broad and vague. If the question is "can Meteor make mobile websites?", then a quick research on SO or a web search engine would quickly get you the answer. A dashboard is just a component of an app, so of course you can make it. If the question is "Can I make multiple apps with Meteor?", then obviously yes. Please heavily refine your question through edits or ask another, more specific question.

Comment: Looking at your question, are you trying to ask for backend(dashboard), frontend(website) and mobile(ios/android/others) apps. Yes, it is possible. **how can i do this ?** . well, [go here](https://www.meteor.com/try), a nice step-by-step tutorial to get some ideas.

Comment: Yes i know this how to make meteor app , My concern is i wanted to a  make  product where user'll just use the mobile app . Admin will use the dashboard . and for the rest of the world there is a website with 3-4 pages . If i make these 3 app with same meteor app , how the mobile build will works ?  meteor may be build whole  app for me with website / dashboard/mobile app but i don't want to build the dashboard/website for mobile . How i can build only mobile app ?